# Credential and location issues with bigquery_datatransfer Python APIs

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am an Owner of a GCP project. As such, in the BigQuery UI, it is trivially simple for me to copy a dataset (as a one-time operation) in the `us` multi-region as a new dataset with a different name that's also in the `us` multi-region.

However, after scouring the docs, when I try to approximate performing the same task using the Python SDK, two issues arise:

- Unlike all other BigQuery API calls using the GCP Python SDK, my local `gcloud auth` login isn't automatically used.  Instead, I have to `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path to json file>`.  While OK for a POC, that is concerning because this code will be deployed as a `beam.DoFn` at the start of a Dataflow Pipeline Template, and it is not clear how to do the same in that context.  I would vastly prefer to have the code automatically use the service account in its runtime context (be that Google auth on my laptop or our Dataflow service account in GCP), like all other BigQuery calls do. (And yes, I ensured that `gcloud auth login && gcloud auth application-default login` succeeded immediately before trying.) [UPDATE] - This works perfectly using `DataflowRunner`, and uses the expected service account.  It's only the dev ENV that's hosed, requiring a downloaded credentials JSON file.
- With the credentials file supplied, I then get the error: "BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location: us".  However, that can't be true, because I'm able to perform the Copy Dataset just fine in the GCP UI. [UPDATE] After something like 15 tries, this suddenly started working.  Based upon `git` history, nothing relevent changed.  So, this is no longer an issue.

Here's the (comment-annotated) WIP code so far; any pointers are very much appreciated:

```
import argparse
import logging
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import time
import re

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions

from google.cloud import bigquery, bigquery_datatransfer_v1
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp


class BackupDataset(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self, bq_analytics_dataset_option, bq_backup_dataset_ttl_days_option, project):
        self.bq_analytics_dataset = bq_analytics_dataset_option
        self.bq_backup_dataset_ttl_days = bq_backup_dataset_ttl_days_option
        self.project = project

    def create_backup_dataset(self, bq_client, destination_dataset_id):
        logging.info(f"Creating backup dataset with name: {destination_dataset_id} ...")
        query_job = bq_client.query(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {destination_dataset_id}")
        query_job.result() # Wait for job to finish (it usually does immediately, but not always)

    def create_transfer_config(self, bq_client, bqdt_client, source_dataset_id):
        date_s = "{:%Y_%m_%d}".format(date.today())
        destination_dataset_id = f"{source_dataset_id}_{date_s}"
        self.create_backup_dataset(bq_client, destination_dataset_id)

        display_name = f"Backup of {source_dataset_id} on {date_s}"
        logging.info(f"Creating transfer_config with display name: {display_name} ...")

        transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.TransferConfig(
            destination_dataset_id=destination_dataset_id,
            display_name=display_name,
            data_source_id="cross_region_copy",
            params={
                "source_project_id": self.project,
                "source_dataset_id": source_dataset_id,
                "overwrite_destination_table": True
            },
            schedule_options={
                "disable_auto_scheduling": True
            } # run this only once - the default is recurring
        )

        # In order for this call to not puke with "Failed to find a valid credential. The field 'version_info' or 'service_account_name' must be specified.",
        #  the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ENV var must be set to point to a downloaded service account key file on the local machine.
        # Despite the error text, this call does NOT accept a `service_account_name` param.
        # FIXME: Find a way for this to work without ^^ for ease of developer maintenance
        remote_transfer_config = bqdt_client.create_transfer_config(
            parent=bqdt_client.common_project_path(project),
            transfer_config=transfer_config
        )
        logging.info(f"Created transfer_config with name: {remote_transfer_config.name} ...")
        return remote_transfer_config

    def run_transfer_config(self, bqdt_client, config):
        logging.info(f"Running transfer config with name {config.name} ...")
        start_time = Timestamp(seconds=int(time.time()))
        request = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.StartManualTransferRunsRequest(
            { "parent": config.name, "requested_run_time": start_time }
        )
        bqdt_client.start_manual_transfer_runs(request, timeout=360)

    # ...
```

Comment: Woah: on the ~15th time rerunning this code, hoping for different behavior each time, it's now no longer refusing to create the TransferConfig due to the dataset location in the `'us'` multi-region, and it all proceeds to completion. Very confusing, though I'll take computer non-determinism if it works in my favor any time.

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#copy_a_dataset) for more information to Set up authentication for a local development environment ? Is this helpful ?

Comment: Yes - I went over [the dev setup docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-dev) repeatedly, with no luck.  It's really weird because I have 5 other pipelines that work totally fine after a fresh `gcloud auth login && gcloud auth application-default login` ... but not this one.  One more datapoint: this pipeline works great in Dataflow - just like my other 5 pipelines, I don't have to do anything special for it to automatically use the service account.  Only this one refuses to run in dev without a downloaded service account credentials file.